# How do I find the value of $k$ in the expansion?

Tags: binomial-theorem

In the expansion of $\left(5x^3 + \dfrac{k}{x^2}\right)^8$ in descending powers of $x$, where $k$ isn’t equal to zero and the coefficient of $x^4$ is equal to the coefficient of $x^9$. How do I find the value of $k$?

Comment: Use Binomial Theorem.

Comment: Is this $$\left(5x^3+\frac{k}{x^3}\right)^8$$?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray}
\left(5x^3 + \dfrac{k}{x^3}\right)^8 &=& \sum\limits_{i=0}^{8} 
\begin{pmatrix}
8\\i
\end{pmatrix}
\left(5x^3\right)^{8-i}\left(\dfrac{k}{x^3}\right)^i\\
&=& \sum\limits_{i=0}^{8} 
\begin{pmatrix}
8\\i
\end{pmatrix}
\left(k^i\cdot5^{8-i}x^{24-6i}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The $i$th term in the binomial expansion ($0\le i\le 8$) is
$$\binom8i (5x^3)^{8-i}\frac{k^i}{x^{2i}}=\binom8i 5^{8-i}k^i x^{24-5i}.$$
Determine the vakues of $i$ which produce the terms in $x^4$ and in $x^9$,and deduce the equation in $k$ which expresses the equality of the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Use binomial formula:
$$\left(5x^3 + \dfrac{k}{x^2}\right)^8=\sum_{n=0}^8{8\choose n}(5x^3)^n(kx^{-2})^{8-n}=\sum_{n=0}^8 {8\choose n}5^nk^{8-n}x^{5n-16}$$
So:
$$5n-16=4 \Rightarrow n=4; \\
5n-16=9 \Rightarrow n=5$$
Can you finish?
Answer:

> $${8\choose 4}5^4\cdot k^4={8\choose 5}5^5\cdot k^3 \Rightarrow k=4.$$